# How to remove the Options button when having a RTF License inside a Wix installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I have made a bundled installer with Wix.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is the code in my wix file that makes this possible:

```xml
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
          LogoFile="../Images/Logo.png" 
          LicenseFile="../Licenses/License.en-US.rtf" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

This is almost exactly how it should look like. The "Options" simply needs to be removed as this is functionality my employer does not want to support.

I managed to remove the "Options" before when not having the rtf but a link instead. I did it like this by using a `LocalizationFile` which describes the options button and can be removed from there.

I have tried that again like this:

```xml
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
          <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
          LogoFile="../Images/Logo.png" 
          ThemeFile="HyperlinkSidebarTheme.xml"
          LogoSideFile="../Images/dialog.bmp"
          LocalizationFile="HyperlinkTheme.wxl"
          LicenseFile="../Licenses/License.en-US.rtf" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

But that does not work at all. The installer does not even pop up after double clicking on it.

Thus, what is the solution here? I just want to remove the "Options" button. That is all.

So how to remove the Options button when having a RTF License inside a Wix installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication elements attribute SuppressOptionsUI to yes.
See https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html for more details.